# using symbol in vba to fill up cell

Tags: excel, vba

this is my code in vba excel

```
Range("a1").Value = "=" & Chr(34) & beat_name & Chr(34) & char(38)
```

final output

=`"name" & TEXT(TODAY(),"DD/MM/YYYY")`

unable to show & sign in excel sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

```
Sub luxation()
    s = "name "
    Range("A1").Formula = "=" & Chr(34) & s & Chr(34) & " & TEXT(TODAY(),""DD/MM/YYYY"")"
End Sub
```